# Need help designing a DB - for a non DBA

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Google's Cloud Storage & BigQuery. I am not a DBA, I am a programmer. I hope this question is generic enough to help others too.

We've been collecting data from a lot of sources and will soon start collecting data real-time. Currently, each source goes to an independent table. As new data comes in we append it into the corresponding existing table.

Our data analysis requires each record to have a a timestamp. However our source data files are too big to edit before we add them to cloud storage (4+ GB of textual data/file). As far as I know there is no way to append a timestamp column to each row before bringing them in BigQuery, right?

We are thus toying with the idea of creating daily tables for each source. But don't know how this will work when we have real time data coming in.

Any tips/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to automatically add timestamps to a table, although that is a feature that we're considering.

You say your source files are too big to edit before putting in cloud storage... does that mean that the entire source file should have the same timestamp? If so, you could import to a new BigQuery table without a timestamp, then run a query that basically copies the table but adds a timestamp. For example, `SELECT all,fields, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() FROM my.temp_table` (you will likely want to use allow_large_results and set a destination table for that query). If you want to get a little bit trickier, you could use the dataset.**DATASET** pseudo-table to get the modified time of the table, and then add it as a column to your table either in a separate query or in a JOIN. Here is how you'd use the **DATASET** pseudo-table to get the last modified time:

```
SELECT MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(last_modified_time) AS time 
FROM [publicdata:samples.__DATASET__] 
WHERE table_id = 'wikipedia'
```

Another alternative to consider is the BigQuery streaming API (More info [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery)). This lets you insert single rows or groups of rows into a table just by posting them directly to bigquery. This may save you a couple of steps.

Creating daily tables is a reasonable option, depending on how you plan to query the data and how many input sources you have. If this is going to make your queries span hundreds of tables, you're likely going to see poor performance. Note that if you need timestamps because you want to limit your queries to certain dates and those dates are within the last 7 days, you can use the time range decorators (documented [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#tabledecorators)).

Comment: Thank you! This helps. I'm going to look into these options.